# How to calculate percent increase/decrease using previous value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that returns total value of sales grouped by month. I would like to add a column that returns the growth/decrease in percentage comparing with previous rows.

I have tried already to use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`, creating a variable `@var :=`, but nothing is really working. Ideally my result would be:

```
Month | Sales | Perc
1     | 100   | 0
2     | 150   | 50
3     | 100   | -33.33
```

The calculation to be done is: `((actual_value - previous_value) / previous_value) *100`

About the tables, I working with `sales`, `products`, `sales_items`, so my query to retrieve the total amount of sales grouped by month is:

```sql
SELECT 
    MONTH(s.sale_date) AS Month,
    SUM(p.retail_price * si.quantity) AS Sales_Amount
FROM sales s
INNER JOIN sales_items si ON s.sale_id = si.sale_id
INNER JOIN products p ON si.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE YEAR(s.sale_date) = '2018'
GROUP BY month 
ORDER BY month;
```

As I'm using `SUM` to summarise the items of the sales and aggregating that into each `sale_id`, and after grouping by month, it seems complicated to use that value into a new column, so it would be great if someone has some idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can turn the aggregate query to a subquery and use window function `LAG` to access the value of the previous month, like:

```
SELECT 
    Sales_Month, 
    Sales_Amount, 
    ( Sales_Amount - LAG(Sales_Amount) OVER(ORDER BY Sales_Month) )
        /LAG(Sales_Amount) OVER(ORDER BY Sales_Month) * 100 AS Percent_Increase
FROM (
    SELECT 
        MONTH(s.sale_date) AS Sales_Month,
        SUM(p.retail_price * si.quantity) AS Sales_Amount
    FROM sales s
    INNER JOIN sales_items si ON s.sale_id = si.sale_id
    INNER JOIN products p ON si.product_id = p.product_id
    WHERE YEAR(s.sale_date) = '2018'
    GROUP BY Sales_Month 
) x
ORDER BY Sales_Month
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new column "PrevMonthSales". To do that you have to join your query with itself :

```
SELECT ...
FROM
(...your_query...) s1
LEFT JOIN (...your_query...) s2 ON s2.Month = s1.Month - 1
```

In your case:

```
SELECT s1.Month, s1.Sales_Amount, 
    COALESCE(s2.Sales_Amount, 0) "PrevMonthSales",
CASE
    WHEN s1.Sales_Amount = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE     (s1.Sales_Amount - COALESCE(s2.Sales_Amount, 0)) / s1.Sales_Amount 
END "Percent"
FROM
    (...your_query...) s1
    LEFT JOIN (...your_query...) s2 ON s2.Month = s1.Month - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Make below a temp table called month_sales

```
SELECT 
MONTH(s.sale_date) AS Month,
SUM(p.retail_price * si.quantity) AS Sales_Amount
FROM sales s
INNER JOIN sales_items si ON s.sale_id = si.sale_id
INNER JOIN products p ON si.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE YEAR(s.sale_date) = '2018'
GROUP BY month 
ORDER BY month;
```

Query to find month over month difference is :

```
SELECT *, 
case 
when m2.Sales_Amount is null then 0 
else (m2.Sales_Amount - m1.Sales_Amount)/m1.Sales_Amount 
end as Perc
FROM month_sales m1
left Join month_sales m2
WHERE m1.month = m2.month - 1
```